# (AS3) Deterministic JSON String from an object?

Tags: json, actionscript-3, object

```
var obj:Object = {a:"foo", b:"bar", c:"baz", d:"qux"};
trace(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

What determines what order the values of this object get added to the JSON string?

I need the JSON to always be the exact same, so I can't have them being in a different order which they seem to be across different clients.

Context: I'm hashing the JSON string, and comparing the hashes on a server to determine if a client is desynced.

Comment: Not going to work with generic objects as Flash Player enumerates them out of blue. However, you can go for Proxy class and its proxy method nextName() and hat just **might** solve your problem: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html#nextName(). Otherwise, you will have to compose your own stringify() method, it is not that difficult.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Proxy class. I gave the reference material a shot, but it's a little over my head. I suppose I'll write my own stringify() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't rely on JSON object keys to be in any order. If you want to create a consistent hash you need to sort the keys into an array and hash that:

```
var fields:Array = [];
for (var key:String in obj) {
  fields.push({key: key, value: obj[key]});
}
fields.sortOn("key");
hash(fields);
```